# Bootstrap 3.2 carousel hiding behind navbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.2 to make a navbar and carousel but the carousel hides under navbar when I reduce the browser width to mobile.

In response to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174344/bootstrap-navbar-overtop-carousel), I tried the solution provided but then the carousel is no more responsive.

I was following the example on Bootstrap's website, but there is no example for carousel on [their components page](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.2.0/docs/components/). So I saw the code for carousel from the templates on their homepage.Don't no why its hiding? Am I using the incorrect class?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InsaneCoder/yyjeqshd/).

My code for carousel :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="images/carousel_large_01.jpg" alt="First slide">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                      <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                      <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="images/carousel_large_02.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                      <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="images/carousel_large_03.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                      <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top ... you need to add padding on the body

Comment: @Danko: I tried it but still the same problem. It seems the carousel `caption` is hiding inside the carousel `div`

Comment: Yep now I see ... but seems tricky to solve since your caption is positioned 20px from the bottom. Is too many info

Comment: What I thnik you can do is reduce the info and change styles in custom way like this http://jsfiddle.net/yyjeqshd/1/ ... maybe hide also the bullets or some that way

Comment: @Danko : Ya thats a good workaround but not the solution.I am still struggling to find the solution.The example-template on Bootstrap's website has correct-working carousel.

Comment: I found the solution myself and that's really basic thing. Actually I need to give some height to the carousel item. Then the height will adjust properly. Yes, `margin-top` or `padding-top` is also required accordingly but this is secondary. The major problem was the height, which was making the carousel contents to hide inside ots own box. I think its the right solution, though I would like to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

IF you remove the `navbar-fixed-top` class then the carousel looks like you want. if you want to use   `navbar-fixed-top` class and also want that the carousel will show below the navbar the add some custom css like, `.someclass{margin-top:20px;}` or add some of the bootstrap classes like jumbotron etc..

Adding `navbar-fixed-top` will fixed/stick the navbar on top that's why the carousel will hide behind it.

You can also look at [This](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) for responsive classes